# Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed. - XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I got this error when using XAMPP.

```
MySQL said: 

Cannot connect: invalid settings.  

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.  

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the   
connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration  
and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator   
of the MySQL server.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that no exact duplicate installations of PHP and phpMyAdmin are installed alongside each other (maybe one of them was installed by XAMPP), and if so remove one of the duplicates.
2. Remove and reinstall mysql-server.

   ```
   sudo apt purge mysql-server  
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```